# Unable to edit questions/answers edit button not working

Tags: support, bug, editing

It has come to my attention that the edit button is not working in ai.stack Exchange .

I am getting below error message, hence raising the issue.

Kindly help due to this, I am unable to edit and make improvements to questions with formula but appear as plain text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Which question were you trying to edit?
I get exactly that message (in the iOS app) when I'm trying to submit a (suggested) edit on a post which already has a pending suggested edit. When using the website, you're blocked from composing the edit, but the mobile apps are different (which [won't change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232)) and show an error only after trying to submit an edit.